# How do I fix a tear in model

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I don't know how to explain it but I'm pretty sure a picture is more than a thousand words. Problem is I have this tear in my model. How can I fix this? [image]

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if this is to merge the selected vertices, use Alt+M

Answer (score 6):

Selecting those 2 split vertices hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> then merge either at first/last selected or center